# ASP.NET Identity 2 GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id) is there a timeout for the link generated?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, email-confirmation

I am using the most recent Identity 2 package in my MVC 5 program.

In the Register method of the Account controller when a user is registered. it sends an email to the user's email account with a link to click to verify the account.

I have found that If I create a dummy user and immediately check my email to register the account it verifies successfully.

If I wait on clicking on the link in the email, all I get is 
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.

Is there a time out on this email link?   And if so is there anyway to extend the timeout of this link?

Comment: According to http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/features-api/account-confirmation-and-password-recovery-with-aspnet-identity the default TokenLifespan is 1 day.

Comment: http://tech.trailmax.info/2015/05/asp-net-identity-invalid-token-for-password-reset-or-email-confirmation/ mentions a possible reason this issue is occuring... token is a Base64 string. Base64 strings are not safe to pass as a URL parameters as special characters there can be interpreted incorrectly by browsers. So you need to do url-encode them to avoid mis-interpretation of the token:

Comment: He is right. The token string is converted into base 64 then decoded from base64 when validated. I was wrong before about the default token lifespan. Did encoding the string solve the issue?

Comment: Been away from my code for the last 36 hours.  Will have to apply it when i get home tomorrow,  and see.

Comment: I was able to verify in my template files I am using, the tokencode was not being url encoded.  This is probably why the email link was just sending back an error when clicked.

Comment: Great to know this for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

Since no one has provided an answer here, I will. The OP's problem was that no URL encoding the resulting token occurred.

```
 var code = Url.Encode(await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId))
```

or

```
var code  = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(userId))
```

If you are encoding, check the lifespan.